# How to display Grand Total for only one column in pivot table in Oracle Analytics Server?

Tags: oracle, obiee, oas

We have a requirement to display column totals in pivot table, but only for one measure column. Is this even possible in OAS?
Here how our pivot view structure looks:

```
                   Store 1              Store 2             Store 3      

Product Type 1     M1 M2 M3             M1 M2 M3            M1 M2 M3
```

Rows : Product Type dimension column
columns: Stores
Measures : M1, M2, M3

If we click in pivot properties to display column totals then we are getting totals for all measure columns :

```
                   Store 1              Store 2             Store 3      M1 Tot M2 Tot M3 Tot 

Product Type 1     M1 M2 M3             M1 M2 M3            M1 M2 M3
```

But our client wants to have only M2 measure total in column grand total section :

```
                   Store 1              Store 2             Store 3     M2 Total 

Product Type 1     M1 M2 M3             M1 M2 M3            M1 M2 M3
```

Is there any workaround to achive this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, If you know the formula for the M2 Total, you can make a new custom column with it.

For example:
Create a column `M2 Total` in Criteria using formula : `SUM(M2_AMOUNT)` (or other formula)